# Include or exclude (license) files from package data with pyproject.toml and setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

### TL;DR

How does one reliably include files from `LICENSES/` (REUSE-style) in source archive and wheels for a Python package with a `src/` layout? How does one exclude specific files?

### Details

I have a project structure that looks like

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── LICENSES
│   ├── MAIN.txt
│   ├── SECUNDARY.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── random_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo1.cpp
│   ├── foo2.cpp
│   ├── submodule1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── bar1.cpp
│   ├── submodule2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── bar2.cpp
```

The `pyproject.toml` looks like

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "random_package"
version = "0.1.0"
license = {file = "LICENSES/MAIN.txt"}

[metadata]                          # EDIT: metadata was the issue
license-files = ["LICENSES/*.txt"]  # this line should be in [tool.setuptools]

[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "."}
include-package-data = true  # tried both true and false

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["random_package*"]
```

How do I include all cpp files *except* `submodule1/bar1.cpp` into the installation?

I have tried the following entries in the toml (one at a time):

```ini
[tool.setuptools.exclude-package-data]
"*" = ["bar1.cpp"]
"random_package.submodule1" = ["bar1.cpp"]
```

I even set `include-package-data` to false and entered cpp files manually (except bar1.cpp) and even that did not work for both source and wheels.

Nothing works reliably: for any and all combinations of these options, I always get bar1.cpp in either the zip/tar.gz archive or the wheel when I do `python -m build`.

As for the license files, I get `LICENSE/MAIN.txt` in the source build, but not the others and no licenses are present in the wheels.

### Partial solution

I have something that works for source dist using a `MANIFEST.in` with an include for the `LICENSES/*.txt` files and a manual include for the .cpp files instead of the data options in `pyproject.toml` but even this does not work for the wheel: I don't get the licenses in `random_package-0.1.0.dist-info`.

Am I wrong in expecting the license files in the wheel? With the old `setup.py` scheme, back when I was using a single `License.txt` file, I did get the license file in there... And is there no way to do that with the toml alone?

Comment: My impression is that the situation regarding licenses in Python packaging is a bit messy right now. There is [_PEP 639_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0639/) to straighten things up, but it has been in "*Draft*" status for a long while now. There is a [discussion here](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-639-round-2-improving-license-clarity-with-better-package-metadata/12622/90) if you want to follow the progress. -- I guess if I were you I would check [*setuptools* ticket tracker](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues), and open a ticket to ask if there isn't one yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that I was mistaken about the location of `license-files` (I first saw it [in the "metadata" section](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#metadata) on the doc); it must actually be in `[tool.setuptools]`.
The other data include issue was maybe a cache issue, it seems to work in the following `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "random_package"
license = {file = "LICENSES/MAIN.txt"}
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "."}
include-package-data = false
license-files = ["LICENSES/*.txt"]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["random_package*"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
random_package = ["*.cpp"]

[tool.setuptools.exclude-package-data]
"*" = ["bar1.cpp"]
```

With this, no `MANIFEST.in` file is required.